# my popup doesn't appear why?

Tags: php, html, alert

```
echo '<a href="editContact.php?edit=1&id= '.$pid .'&cid= '.$cid.'"><img src="images/edit.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>    <a href="delete.php?cid='.$row["ContactID"].'&id='. $pid . '&createdby='. $row["CreatedBy"] . '" onclick=\"return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this contact?");\" >
```

My alert box work fine in HTML, however when I tried to echo it out in PHP, it didn't work, however I still can delete, can somebody help me?

Comment: Whats the extension of your file??Is it .html or .php

Comment: There is no `echo` closing at the very end, you need `";`, is it a typo?

Comment: It is a typo,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have escaped the wrong quotes.

```
onclick=\"return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this contact?");\"
```

Try this:

```
onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to remove this contact?\');"
```

...since you're wrapping the echo with single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
echo '<a href="editContact.php?edit=1&id= '.$pid .'&cid= '.$cid.'"><img src="images/edit.png" width="30" height="30" /></a> 
    <a href="delete.php?cid='.$row["ContactID"].'&id='. $pid . '&createdby='. $row["CreatedBy"] . 
        '" onclick="return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to remove this contact?\");" >';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape the quotes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

You may also find it convenient that variable names, when used in **double**-quoted strings in PHP, [they are interpreted instead of being string literals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 0):

You can not user " inside of " try with `onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this contact?');\"`